# Opening multiple URLs with window.open

Tags: javascript, arrays, window.open

I'm pretty new to javascript, so apologies for the beginner question.  Basically, I am having some problems with the window.open() method.

My code essentially takes a user string, adds a couple different variations to it, and  those searches those different variations, and then is supposed to open a new window with each result.  However, it seems that after my first window.open statement, the code stops executing.  This is what I am working with:

```
var searchStrings = new Array(url1, url2, url3);

var arrayLength = searchStrings.length;
for (var i = 0; i<arrayLength; i++) {
    window.open(searchStrings[i]);
}
```

I have tested the loop with code other than window.open to make sure it iterates through the array correctly, and I have set i to values higher than 0 to test opening the second or third item in the array.

It seems like window.open is only meant to be used once, or am I doing something else incorrectly?

Comment: Browsers only allow one `window.open` per user interaction. Imagine what ads would look like if this wasn't the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this out: https://javascript.info/popup-windows

This documents correct usage of window.open() functionality.

Modern browsers block that kind of execution, due the risk of mis-using the functionality. 
Imagine, you enter the page and 10x windows open, for no reason.

Actually, have a look you code works but chrome blocks the window and on the address bar you are notified. However Firefox blocks it completely, until manually disable the option.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the useful information, I feel like a dummy for not checking browser security settings first.  After adding the URL to security/pop-up exemption list it is now working.  This web page is just for internal use by myself and one other person, so that will work fine for our purposes.

Answer (score 1):

`windows.open` can takes second parameter(name), if you want open multiple URLs you have to set unique name for each one. in your scenario you cant use this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
     window.open(searchStrings[i], '_wnd' + i);
}
```

Comment: I believe your post would be better received if rather than saying you CAN'T do this: ... You gave an a working example.
I took your reply and built a working version for my unique case with an incremented variable in PHP:
     onclick="window.open(this.href,'targetWindow<?php echo $_SESSION['incrID'] ?>','toolbar=no,....

Comment: i guess "cant" was a typo. Doesn't work though.