# From Array to individual string in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string

there is a problem with my code I try to split array values to single individual strings that contains part of links.

I tried with `dele.join()` , but still the output is single string with coma separation

```js
$(function () {

            $("#selectedel").click(function () {
                var dele =[]; // Array look like this  ["/delete.php?id=1","/delete.php?id=2","/delete.php?id=3"]
                $.each($("input:checkbox[name='dele']:checked"), function () {
                    dele.push($(this).val());

                });
                console.log(dele.toString());
                console.log(dele.join(","));
            })


        });
```

output of this code is

```
/delete.php?id=1,/delete.php?id=2,/delete.php?id=3
```

The output that i want is

```
/delete.php?id=1
/delete.php?id=2
/delete.php?id=3
```

Which in the end i want to open this links with `window.open()` at once .

Thank you in advance

Comment: What about `.join('\n')`?

Comment: _"Which in the end i want to open this links with window.open() at once"_ - `window.open()` only opens one URL per call.

Comment: @Andreas yes but if i separate them in individual strings ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox is still 1 string , just on new line

Comment: if you want to open multiple link with `window.open()`, you need to have multiple calls.
the easiest way would be toput the instruction into your `each` loop

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea. Even if you call them separately, most modern browsers block that kind of execution. 

Check https://javascript.info/popup-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
["/delete.php?id=1", "/delete.php?id=2", "/delete.php?id=3"].map((url) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {};
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.send();
});
```

Comment: still opens just one

Comment: This sounds like an answer then
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593619/opening-multiple-urls-with-window-open

Comment: What is the purpose of opening 3 links? Maybe its better for you to receive the content in ajax request and render on the same window?

Comment: the purpose is deleting rows from a csv file , it was just single before with anchor ```<a href="delete.php?id=i>X</a>"``` now i want to can multiple choices with a checkbox ... that i try to do yes .. it will be better with ajax but i dont know how to do it

Comment: I edited the answer, Its very simple and fast example, Try search about XHR in js, or fetch in ts/react/angular etc... to learn more and develop it further to match your requirement